# How to work with object initialization and classes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a class

```
  class TestFixture
    {
        public string a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }
        public int c { get; set; }
        public string d { get; set; }

        public string e { get ; set ; }
        public int f { get; set; }
        public int g { get; set; }
        public bool h { get; set; }
        public string i { get; set; }
        public bool j { get; set; }
        public bool k { get; set; }

        public TestFixture()
        {
            e= dosomething(a, b);
            f= false;
            g = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmmss");
            h= TestName.Equals("1") && b.Equals("2") ? 1000 : 1;
            i= 10000000;
            j= a.Equals("FOT");
            k = false;
        }
    }
```

I want to define new TestFixture as SO

```
new TestFixture { a = "", b = 1, c=2, d="" };
```

while the rest of properties should be auto defined as it written in constructor.

Is it possible ?

Comment: as mtijn said; try what u wrote...

Comment: This may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Have you even tried to run it;
That will do exactly what you want, and your constructor will be called.

Comment: Obviously i did try to run it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Using an object initializer does not skip calling the constructor.

```
TestFixture fixture = new TestFixture() // or just new TestFixture { ... }
{
    a = "", 
    b = 1, 
    c = 2, 
    d = "" 
};
```

This will call the constructor you've defined and then set `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in your object initializer.

---

Pop a breakpoint in your constructor and run your debugger. This is should show you how and when things in your code are called.

[Debugging in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)

---

Refactored:

```
public class TestFixture
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }

    // dosomething should check for null strings
    public string e { get { return dosomething(a, b); } }
    public int f { get; set; }
    public int g { get; set; }
    public bool h 
    {
        get { return TestName.Equals("1") && b.Equals("2") ? 1000 : 1; }
    }
    public string i { get; set; }
    public bool j { get { return a != null && a.Equals("FOT"); } }
    public bool k { get; set; }

    public TestFixture(string a, int b, int c, string d) 
        : this() 
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public TestFixture()
    {
        f = false;
        g = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmmss");
        i = 10000000;
        k = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i guess there is no easy way to do that, then i will go back to default object initialization with constructor. Thanks anyways learned thing or two from your code.

Answer (score 1):

@hunter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649568/how-to-work-with-object-initialization-and-classes-in-c/7649618#7649618) is correct, you can use object initializer syntax, and those properties will be set after your constructor runs. However, I'd like to point out some flaws you may have with your code

```
public TestFixture()
{
    e= dosomething(a, b);
    f= false;
    g = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmmss");
    h= TestName.Equals("1") && b.Equals("2") ? 1000 : 1;
    i= 10000000;
    j= a.Equals("FOT");
    k = false;
}
```

This code does not set `a` or `b`, but you have things that depend on their values (`e`, `g`, `j`). Object initializer syntax is *not* going to be useful here, you have to have proper defaults for these values if other values in the constructor will depend upon them.

As an example, when you write `var obj = new Bar() { A = "foo" };`, that will expand to

```
var obj = new Bar(); // constructor runs 
obj.A = "Foo"; // a is set
```

Clearly, the code in the constructor that looks at `A` will not see the value `"Foo"`. If you *need* it to see this value, object initialization strategy is not going to help. You need a *constructor overload* that takes the value to be stored in `A`.

```
var obj = new Bar("Foo");
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on which order object initializers are called once object created.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you would like to the a, b, c and d properties to be initialized with the given values before the constructor runs. Unfortunately, that is not possible this way, because the default constructor always runs before the object intializers.
I advise you to do something like this instead:

```
class TestFixture
{
    //... properties

    public TestFixture()
    {
        this.init();
    }

    public TestFixture(string a, int b, int c, string d)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;

        this.init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        e= dosomething(a, b);
        f= false;
        g = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmmss");
        h= TestName.Equals("1") && b.Equals("2") ? 1000 : 1;
        i= 10000000;
        j= a.Equals("FOT");
        k = false;
    }
}
```

This way you can init the a, b, c and d properties before the other initializer code runs.